# python run list of functions untill one passes

Tags: python

I run a  command using python in linux, and I have a several different method of verifying based on system type. My question is can I make the verify function take a list of functions instead creating all the combinations.

currently I have:

```
def verify_A(*args):
    checks the commands was successful using method A

def verify_B(*args):
    checks the commands was successful using method B

def run_command(*args)
    runs the commands on linux terminal, no checking

def run_and_verify_A(*args):
     run_command(*args)
     verify_A(*args)

def run_and_verify_B(*args):
    run_command(*args)
    verify_B(*args)

def run_and_verify_All(*args):
    run_command(*args)
    if not verify_A(*args):
        verify_B(*args)
```

what I want is:

```
def run_command(*args)
    runs the commands on linux terminal, no checking


verify_list=['verify_A','verify_B']

def run_and_verify(verify_list):
     run_command(*args)
     for func in verify_list:
         if eval(func):
             print "verification passed"
             return True
        else:
             print "verification is failed... running next verify method"
```

but my run_and verify function is not working as expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put functions in a list:

```
def foo():
    return something

def bar():
    return stuff

lst = [foo, bar]

for func in lst:
    if func()
        print('passed...')
        break  # or return, however you decide to set it up
    else:
        print('failed...')
```

Comment: but i dont want to run bar, if foo is successful.

Comment: this is crazy, this worked.  i had the same thing, but it was running my code 6 times for each char in the list as f,o,o,b,a,r. anyways, Thanks

Comment: You had them as strings not as Python objects (functions are objects in Python).

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the functions have the same signatures, Create a list of functions and use `any` to evaluate then in the order specified. The short-circuit property of `any` essentially helps you to ignore all functions past the one that has a success

**Example**

```
verify = [verify_A, verify_B, run_and_verify_A, 
          run_and_verify_B, run_and_verify_Allrun_and_verify_All]


def run_and_verify(verify_list, *args):
     run_command(*args)
     if any(fn(*args) for fn in verify_list):
         print "verification passed"
     else:
         print "verification is failed... running next verify method"
```

Comment: def foo():
         print "something"
         return True

     def bar():
 print "stuff"

lst = [foo(), bar()]

any(lst) returns something and stuff..

Comment: @curious07 If you trying to add more than a (short) line or two of code you should edit your question instead.

Comment: @curious07: Please clarify your comment

Comment: this kind of works but doesn't tell me if verify_A failed. if Verify_B passed. and only prints failed, if all of them failed.